# Saving tab completion possibilities to a file

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Instead of displaying all possibilities on terminal screen, as in:

```
$ ls /etc/<TAB>
Display all 230 possibilities? (y or n)
```

I want to save all possibilities to a file.

`ls /etc/ > file.txt` will not always work. apt-get is an example:

```
$ apt-get <TAB>
autoclean        check            install          update
autoremove       clean            purge            upgrade
build-dep        dist-upgrade     remove           
changelog        dselect-upgrade  source
```

I'm looking for a command like `tabcompletions 'ls /etc/'` which outputs all possibilities, so that I can run a command like the one below, which compares the tab completion possibilities for two commands:

```
diff <(tabcompletions 'ls ') <(tabcompletions 'cd ')
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23900/how-to-pipe-the-list-of-commands-displayed-by-of-tab-complete

Answer (score 5):

In your `~/.bashrc` you probably have something like this:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix
then
    source /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Now, that's where to continue looking, and the header of `_quote_readline_by_ref` contains the necessary hint:

```
compgen -f /etc/
```

Tracing this back, it turns out that (via `type compgen`) compgen is a "shell builtin", which means it should appear in `man bash`:

```
compgen [option] [word]
       Generate possible completion matches for word according to the options ...
```

Comment: An example using a completion function, as `_apt_get` would be interesting.

Comment: @enzotib `compgen -F _apt_get`, except that it's not so simple: you would need to set a bunch of variables to emulate the real completion system. Zsh is even worse, the completion primitives (`compadd`, `compset`) only work if called from a completion widget, which in turns only works from the line editor, not from a script or even from a command line.

Answer (score 4):

Although, a crude method, you could use the command `script`

```
$ script -a lsdiff
Script started, file is lsdiff
$ ls <TAB>
a b c ...
$ <Ctrl-D>
Script done, file is lsdiff
```

Repeat the above for `cd` and compare the difference.

Answer (score 0):

For the `ls /etc/<TAB>` auto-completion case, do this:

```bash
# print to screen
compgen -f /etc/ | sort
# store to file
compgen -f /etc/ | sort > output.txt
# print to screen *and* store to file
compgen -f /etc/ | sort | tee output.txt
```

See `help compgen` for more info. `compgen` apparently stands for "completion generator".

See also `man bash` and search for `compgen`, since it is a built-in executable built in to bash. `man bash` has a *lot* more info about the `compgen` command.

Ex: `compgen -A command <cmd>` is the same as `compgen -c <cmd>`, and `compgen -A file` is the same as `compgen -f`. Search `man bash` for `-A action`.

### See also:

1. [List all binaries from `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120825/114401)
2. [How to pipe the list of commands displayed by "tab complete"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23919/114401)