# List all binaries from $PATH

Tags: bash, shell, path, executable

Is there a one-liner that will list all executables from $PATH in Bash?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it's showing binary, a command which you could run

```
compgen -c
```

(assuming `bash`)

Other useful commands

```
compgen -a # will list all the aliases you could run.
compgen -b # will list all the built-ins you could run.
compgen -k # will list all the keywords you could run.
compgen -A function # will list all the functions you could run.
compgen -A function -abck # will list all the above in one go.
```

Comment: Good to know this command, and I actually need executables for completion. Maybe I use this command instead.

Comment: @jcubic, the shells already do it for command completion Why do it by hand?

Comment: @vonbrand I'm working on the shell in javascript/php and I'm executing shell in non interactive mode.

Comment: Pipe to `sort -V` for sorted output. Ex: to see all executables in your PATH on your system, *and* all aliases, all sorted, run: `compgen -c | sort -V`.

Comment: More details on compgen over at [→Q151118](/q/151118 "Understand \`compgen\` builtin command")

Answer (score 26):

With zsh:

```
whence -pm '*'
```

Or:

```
print -rC1 -- $commands
```

(note that for commands that appear in more than one component of `$PATH`, they will list only the first one).

If you want the commands without the full paths, and sorted for good measure:

```
print -rC1 -- ${(ko)commands}
```

(that is, get the keys of that associative array instead of the values).

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm using bash.

Comment: `whence -pm '*'` will also print directories.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev, Same for the other ones. One may argue it's as expected. If you have a directory in a component of `$PATH`, you may expect it to be executed. `zsh` will actually try to execute the `/var` directory if you enter `PATH=/; var` for instance (and likely fail as I don't think any system allows executing directories).

Comment: `compgen -c` will not include directories, so this seems like a zsh bug. If it's checking if entries are executable, it might as well also check that they're not directories.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev, in `zsh`, that's controlled by the `hashexecutablesonly` option. Checking the type of files is costly especially on network filesystems as you need one `stat()` per file in `$PATH` directories, which is why it's not enabled by default. That's generally good enough in the usual case where there's no garbage in `$PATH` directories, but you can set that option if `$PATH` dirs are only on fast filesystems.

Comment: With `hashexecutablesonly` and a `rehash` it does seem to skip directories. You should add that to the answer, it seems very useful (and brings the answer closer to answering the question as stated)!

Answer (score 15):

In any POSIX shell, without using any external command (assuming `printf` is built in, if not fall back to `echo`) except for the final sorting, and assuming that no executable name contains a newline:

```bsh
{ set -f; IFS=:; for d in $PATH; do set +f; [ -n "$d" ] || d=.; for f in "$d"/.[!.]* "$d"/..?* "$d"/*; do [ -f "$f" ] && [ -x "$f" ] && printf '%s\n' "${f##*/}"; done; done; } | sort
```

If you have no empty component in `$PATH` (use `.` instead) nor components beginning with `-`, nor wildcard characters `\[?*` in either PATH components or executable names, and no executables beginning with `.`, you can simplify this to:

```bsh
{ IFS=:; for d in $PATH; do for f in $d/*; do [ -f $f ] && [ -x $f ] && echo ${f##*/}; done; done; } | sort
```

Using POSIX `find` and `sed`:

```bsh
{ IFS=:; set -f; find -H $PATH -prune -type f -perm -100 -print; } | sed 's!.*/!!' | sort
```

If you're willing to list the rare non-executable file or non-regular file in the path, there's a much simpler way:

```bsh
{ IFS=:; ls -H $PATH; } | sort
```

This skips dot files; if you need them, add the `-A` flag to `ls` if yours has it, or if you want to stick to POSIX: `ls -aH $PATH | grep -Fxv -e . -e ..`

There are simpler solutions [in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120825) and [in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120818/885).

Comment: That assumes that `$PATH` is set and doesn't contain empty components, and that components don't look like find predicates (or ls options). Some of those will also ignore dot files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yeah, ok. Apart from empty components, this falls squarely under the “don't do this” category — PATH is under your control.

Comment: It still doesn't work if the empty element is last (as it usually is). (except in `yash` and `zsh` in sh emulation).

Comment: In your `find` one. `-prune` will prevent listing directories. You probably want `-L` instead of `-H` as you want to include symlinks (common for executables). `-perm -100` gives no guarantee that the file be executable by you (and might (unlikely) exclude executable files).

Answer (score 9):

How about this

```
find ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -executable
```

The string substitution is used with Bash.

Comment: That assumes that `$PATH` is set, doesn't contain wildcard or blank characters, doesn't contain empty components. That assumes GNU find as well. Note that `${var//x/y}` is `ksh` syntax (also supported by zsh and bash). Strictly speaking that also assumes that $PATH components are not `find` predicates either.

Comment: That also assumes that `$PATH` components are not symlinks.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thanks! In other words, usual case.

Comment: Setting `IFS=:` is more robust than doing this substitution. Paths with spaces aren't that uncommon on Windows. Symbolic links are fairly common, but that's easily solved with `-H`.

Comment: @Gilles: of course. however I don't see any reasonable use-case for this question, therefore is no need for a bullet-proof answer.

Comment: It also doesn't work if PATHs contain spaces, like `/Applications/Visual` `Studio` are treated as separate args.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this:

```
IFS=':';for i in $PATH; do test -d "$i" && find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -exec basename {} \;; done
```

**EDIT**:
It seems that this is the only command that don't trigger SELinux alert while reading some of the files in bin directory by apache user.

Comment: Why the `for`? `IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -printf '%f\n'`

Comment: @manatwork will it work for non existing paths?

Comment: @manatwork didn't know that you can do that. need to read more about IFS.

Comment: Well, `find` just outputs messages on stderr for each missing directory. If you redirect stderr to /dev/null, should be fine. (That will also remove Permission denied messages, for existing directories (passing your `test -d`) for which you have no execute permission.)

Comment: That assumes that `$PATH` is set and doesn't contain wildcard characters and doesn't contain empty components. That also assumes the GNU implementation of `find`.

Comment: Because of `-type f` instead of (GNU specific) `-xtype f`, that will also omit symlinks. That will also not list the content of `$PATH` components that are symlinks.

Comment: It would be nice if you would wrap this copy-pastable code in a subshell so that the IFS doesn't stay changed after executing this.

Answer (score 3):

If you can run Python 2 in your shell, the following (ridiculously long) one-liner can be used as well:

```bsh
python2 -c 'import os;import sys;output = lambda(x) : sys.stdout.write(x + "\n"); paths = os.environ["PATH"].split(":") ; listdir = lambda(p) : os.listdir(p) if os.path.isdir(p) else [ ] ; isfile = lambda(x) : True if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(x[0],x[1])) else False ; isexe = lambda(x) : True if os.access(os.path.join(x[0],x[1]), os.X_OK) else False ; map(output,[ os.path.join(p,f) for p in paths for f in listdir(p) if isfile((p,f)) and isexe((p,f)) ])'
```

This was mostly a fun exercise for myself to see if it could be done using one line of Python code without resorting to using the `exec` function. In a more readable form, and with some comments, the code looks like this:

```py
import os
import sys

# This is just to have a function to output something on the screen.
# I'm using Python 2.7 in which 'print' is not a function and cannot
# be used in the 'map' function.
output = lambda(x) : sys.stdout.write(x + "\n")

# Get a list of the components in the PATH environment variable. Will
# abort the program is PATH doesn't exist
paths = os.environ["PATH"].split(":")

# os.listdir raises an error is something is not a path so I'm creating
# a small function that only executes it if 'p' is a directory
listdir = lambda(p) : os.listdir(p) if os.path.isdir(p) else [ ]

# Checks if the path specified by x[0] and x[1] is a file
isfile = lambda(x) : True if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(x[0],x[1])) else False

# Checks if the path specified by x[0] and x[1] has the executable flag set
isexe = lambda(x) : True if os.access(os.path.join(x[0],x[1]), os.X_OK) else False

# Here, I'm using a list comprehension to build a list of all executable files
# in the PATH, and abusing the map function to write every name in the resulting
# list to the screen.
map(output, [ os.path.join(p,f) for p in paths for f in listdir(p) if isfile((p,f)) and isexe((p,f)) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from os.path import expanduser, isdir, join, pathsep

def list_executables():
    paths = os.environ["PATH"].split(pathsep)
    executables = []
    for path in filter(isdir, paths):
        for file_ in os.listdir(path):
            if os.access(join(path, file_), os.X_OK):
                executables.append(file_)
    return executables
```

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS with zsh you can do this:

```
find ${(s/:/)PATH}
```

or, if you want to be fancy:

```
find ${(s/:/)PATH} -maxdepth 1 -perm -u+x -type f | xargs basename
```

Comment: The question was about Bash.

Answer (score 0):

This works in bash on mac:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | xargs -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -perm +111 -type f 2>/dev/null | sort
```